# Why doesn't lambda work properly when dealing with a sequence?

Tags: python, lambda, min

Lambda doesn't seem to work when I try to return a tuple from it that is made from 2 characters which are each the min() of their lists. Normal functions seem to work properly though, so this is a limitation of using lambdas or am I missing something silly? Using list() or tuple() returns an error.

```
import random

randnums = [random.randrange(2, num+3) for num in range(10)]

data = list(range(10))

def get_min(x,y):
    return (min(x), min(y))

print(get_min(data, randnums))

print(list(map(lambda x,y: (min(x), min(y)), data, randnums)))
```

Comment: Why are you using `list` and `map`? You didn't use those with `get_min`. You shouldn't use them with the `lambda`.

Comment: Then how do I return the required output @user2357112

Comment: Just call the function!

Comment: What does "not work" mean?

Comment: I don't get it, how do I call a lambda function

Comment: @MohamedMotaz the *same way you call a normal function*, using parentheses. But `get_min(data, randnums)` is *not equivalent* to `list(map(lambda...))` Your expression is the equivalent to `list(map(get_min, data, randnums))`

Comment: @PeterWood, I passed both data and randnums

Comment: @MohamedMotaz there is a difference between `map(some_func, data_x, data_y)` and `some_func(data_x, data_y)`/

Comment: can somebody add the code detailing how I would call a lambda function?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, can u explain the difference between mapping and using a normal function, and how can i get the exact same thing from both mapping and a normal functiob

Comment: @MohamedMotaz have you read the documentation for `map`? `map(f, some_iterable)` returns an iterator that *maps* function `f` onto *every element* of that iterable. Note, **lambda is irrelevant here**. A `lambda` function **works exactly the same as a regular function**. You can use both with and without `map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just **call the function**!

```
(lambda x,y: (min(x), min(y)))(data, randnums)
```

It's the same exact way you'd call `get_min(data, randnums)`. Function, opening parenthesis, arguments, closing parenthesis, but with `(lambda x,y: (min(x), min(y)))` as the function instead of `get_min`.